# Which is faster? IBAction or Programmatically?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, swift3

I've always had a question about this. 
Is it faster to hook 20 UIButtons to an action or just loop through then and add it programmatically?

```
for button in myButtons {
button.addAction.... etc
    }
```

Comment: There would be little difference.

Comment: Which side though? IBAction or programmatically?

Comment: To answer that need few more info - 1. Are the action methods same and on the same target object ? 2. 20 buttons are on the same screen (!!!) ?

Comment: Yes and yes. So same action and same screen. Sometimes more than 20 buttons!

Comment: If performance really matters, try profiling with Instruments.  Without further context, 20 actions would have marginal difference.  Are these actions added often?

Comment: They are added as needed to different views. Sometimes every 0.2seconds

Comment: @Tushar I can't see anything wrong with 20 buttons on one screen. Tell me, how many buttons are there on a scientific calculator app?

Answer (score 0):

20 buttons added through code will be loaded faster than loading via a resource file. And the selection comfortability depends on the developer.

Yes specific applications e.g calculator or calendar  are right and rare examples, but I commented that in general sense having 20 buttons in a screen is weird.